# Group by isoweek - postgresql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

This is a subquestion based on a previous question:

[Split values from an interval and group by isoweek - Postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42467770/split-values-from-an-interval-and-group-by-isoweek-postgresql)

The question is how to group this by isoweek

```
CREATE TABLE task
    (id int4, start date, stop date, hr int4);    
INSERT INTO task
    (id, start, stop, hr)
VALUES
    (1, '2017-01-01','2017-01-31', 80),
    (2, '2017-01-01','2017-02-28', 120);
```

Based on Patricks answer I found this solution:

```
SELECT id,to_char(iso, 'iyyy-iw'),(hr/weeks)::numeric (5,2) as hr_week 
FROM (SELECT id,hr,generate_series(start,stop,interval '1 week') as iso, 
(stop - start)/7 as weeks FROM task) as sub
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/93ee1/78

The next step is to "group the groups" like this:

```
2016-52 35
2017-01 35
2017-02 35
2017-03 35
2017-04 35
2017-05 15
2017-06 15
2017-07 15
2017-08 15
```

I cannot figure out how to do this. Any help appreciated.

TIA,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/93ee1/101)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE task
    (id int4, start date, stop date, hr int4);    
INSERT INTO task
    (id, start, stop, hr)
VALUES
    (1, '2017-01-01','2017-01-31', 80),
    (2, '2017-01-01','2017-02-28', 120);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
     to_char(iso, 'iyyy-iw')  as YYY_WK
   , max(weeks) as weeks
   , sum((hr/weeks)::numeric (5,2)) as hr_week 
FROM (
    SELECT
       id
     , hr
     , generate_series(start,stop,interval '1 week') as iso
     , (stop - start)/7 as weeks 
    FROM task
    ) as sub
group by
     to_char(iso, 'iyyy-iw')
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/93ee1/101/0)**:

```
|  yyy_wk | weeks | hr_week |
|---------|-------|---------|
| 2017-08 |     8 |      15 |
| 2017-06 |     8 |      15 |
| 2017-02 |     8 |      35 |
| 2017-03 |     8 |      35 |
| 2017-07 |     8 |      15 |
| 2016-52 |     8 |      35 |
| 2017-05 |     8 |      15 |
| 2017-01 |     8 |      35 |
| 2017-04 |     8 |      35 |
```

Comment: I hope this will cover empty weeks as well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile I found another solution, based on cte. This however does not cover empty weeks but is a solution as well. I will consider @used-by-already as an more reliable answer.

```
WITH list as (
SELECT id,to_char(iso, 'iyyy-iw'),(hr/weeks)::numeric (5,2) as hr_week 
FROM (SELECT id,hr,generate_series(start,stop,interval '1 week') as iso, 
(stop - start)/7 as weeks FROM task) as sub)

SELECT DISTINCT ON (week) week, sum(hr_week) 
FROM list 
GROUP BY 1
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/93ee1/113